# common lisp latitude and longitude to course

Tags: location, common-lisp

The basis of my current project is to write some code that can calculate a direct course between two points. There was no code I could find online for common lisp, so I had to translate what I had available. I think I did so correctly, but it still won't run. Any Help would be appreciated.

I hit a roadblock, any ideas? The following errors occurs:

```
;Compiler warnings for "nav.lisp" :
;   In COURSE-CALC: Undefined function LAT1
;   In COURSE-CALC: Undefined function LAT1
;   In COURSE-CALC: Undefined function LAT2
```

What I don't understand is why the compiler thinks that the variables are functions.

here is what I have so far:

```
 (defparameter *earth-radius* 6372.8)
 (defparameter *e* (exp 1))
 (defparameter *rad-conv* (/ pi 180))

 (defun km->miles (km)
    (* km .621371))
(defun miles->km (miles)
    (* miles 1.60934))

 (defun mph->mpm (mph)
    (/ mph 60))

(defun kph->kpm (kph)
    (/ kph 60))

(defun deg->rad (deg)
  (* deg *rad-conv*))

(defun haversine (x)
  (expt (sin (/ x 2)) 2))

(defun dist-rad (lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2)
  (let* ((hlat (haversine (- lat2 lat1)))
         (hlng (haversine (- lng2 lng1)))
         (root (sqrt (+ hlat (* (cos lat1) (cos lat2) hlng)))))
    (* 2 *earth-radius* (asin root))))

(defun dist-deg (lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2)
  (dist-rad (deg->rad lat1)
            (deg->rad lng1)
            (deg->rad lat2)
            (deg->rad lng2)))

;acos(sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(d)) / (sin(d)*cos(lat1))
(defun course-calc (lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2)
  (acos(/(*(- (sin(lat2)) (sin(lat1))) (cos(dist-rad lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2))) (* (sin(dist-rad lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2)) (cos(lat1))))))

(defun course (lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2)
  (if (< (sin (- lng1 lng2)) 0)
      (course-calc lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2) 
      (-(* 2 pi)(course-calc lat1 lng1 lat2 lng2))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have too many parentheses in the definition of `course-calc`. The expression

```
(sin(lat2))
```

calls the function `lat2`, then `sin` on whatever `lat2` returns. Your `lat2`, howerver, is not a function but a variable. What you want to say is

```
(sin lat2)
```

The same goes for `(cos(lat1))` at the end of the line.